# Return the value of user meta key and change the value to number

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_value_bank3_code', 'my_custom_population_showbank' );
function my_custom_population_showbank( $value ) {
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$users = $current_user->userpinn;
return $users;

}
```

But i want if the value of the user metakey is Canada it should change Canada to a number like 340
but if the value is America it should return 500

The concept is that i want to pull user meta key of users in my website by their country. so the $current_user->userpinn; out puts the current user country on his metakey. using userpinn as country metakey.

- Now i want if the current user is from England it should return 400
- IF current user is from United Kingdom it should return 580
- If the current user is from Canada it should return 320

Thats how i want to do it for each different country, instead of returning the England it should return number which is 400, and i want the function on a single text field or number field, not on a drop down list.

Comment: using switch case you can archive your functionality

Comment: in which meta value is stored the country ?

Comment: Please try the below code and feel free to ask if you have any concern or query.

Answer (score 0):

```
$country_name = 'your user meta value here';
switch ($country_name) {
    case "England":
        $return_country_code = 400;
        break;
    case "United Kingdom":
        $return_country_code = 580;
        break;
    case "Canada":
        $return_country_code = 320;
        break;
    default:
        $return_country_code = 400; //Default code if you want.

    return $return_country_code;
}
```